# Xpath ImportXML Currency Rate

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to import the right XPath or import function to get the live conversion amount on this page:

https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=AUD&To=PHP

Need this number:

[image: 0]

I am stuck here -

[image]

Comment: Seem like function `importxml` only processes the original Html of the page. If that's the case, this data is not going to be found there, as it's generated by scripts after the page loads. Try Selenium or iMacros.

Comment: **ANSWER**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcn0e.png